# How to determine coercive functions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, coercive

A continuous function $f(x)$ that is defined on $R^n$ is called coercive if $\lim\limits_{\Vert x \Vert \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=+ \infty$.

I am finding it difficult to understand how the **norm** of these functions are computed in order to show that they are coercive.
$a) f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
\\b)f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-3xy\\c)f(x,y,z)=e^{x^2}+e^{y^2}+e^{z^2}$

To show that they are coercive I have to show that as norm goes to infinity the function too should go to infinity right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: I think your definition of coercive is not right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function

Comment: The definition of coercive is fine. It is the definition commonly used in nonlinear programming.

Answer (score 4):

To prove that the function is coercive, we need to show that its value goes to $\infty$, as the norm becomes $\infty$.

1)$$ f(x,y)=x^2+y^2= \infty \\ as  \left \| x \right \|\rightarrow \infty $$
i.e. $||x||=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$

Hence , $f(x)$  is coercive.

2)$$ f(x,y)=x^4+y^4- 3xy
\\ \because ((x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2))=3xy (\frac{2}{3}) 
\\f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-(\frac{3}{2})( (x+y)^2)-(x^2+y^2))
\\ \leq x^4+y^4 + (\frac{3}{2})(x^2+y^2)\\
\leq (x^2+y^2)^2 + (\frac{3}{2})(x^2+y^2)
\\
 \therefore  f(x,y)=\infty 
\\ as  \left \| x \right \|\rightarrow \infty $$
i.e. $||x||=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$

Hence , $f(x)$  is coercive.

3)$$ f(x,y,z)=e^{x^{2}} + e^{y^{2}}+ e^{z^{2}} 
\\
\approx (1+x^{2})+(1+y^{2})+(1+z^{2}) 
= \infty $$
$$\\ as  \left \| x \right \|\rightarrow \infty $$
i.e. $||x||=\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Hence , $f(x)$  is coercive.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the first function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$. This function can be written in terms of vectors as $f(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{x}\|^2$. Now you can see that $f(\mathbf{x}) \to \infty$ as $\|\mathbf{x}\| \to \infty$.

Here is a hint for the second function. Use the inequality $-\frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \leq -3xy$ to derive a lower bound for $f(x,y)$. Show that for any $M > 0$ there exists a number $K > 0$ such that $f(x,y) > M$ whenever $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > K$.

Comment: What I don't understand is **what** is this $||x||$

Comment: The function $\|\cdot\|$ is called a norm. In this case you are using the Euclidean norm or $2$-norm. For any vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the $2$-norm of $\mathbf{x}$ is defined by $\|\mathbf{x}\| = (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)^{1/2}$. In two variables $x$ and $y$ you have $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: @K.Miller SO even for $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-3xy$ as there are only two variables is the norm = $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. For $f(x,y,z)=e^{x^2}+e^{y^2}+e^{z^2}$ as there are three variables is the norm = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Comment: No. The norm is just a function that maps vectors to a positive real number. You need to rearrange $f(x,y)$ to show that as $x^2 + y^2$ grows large so to does $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @K.Miller I understand that I have to show function grows as norm grows. But my problem is finding out what is **norm**. Is the norm for $x^4+y^4-3xy$ is $\sqrt{x^8+y^8}$

Comment: You are confusing the norm of a vector and the function $f$. The norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|$ provides a notion of size for a vector $\mathbf{x}$. The norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|$ is always defined in the same way. You need to find a way relating the function $f$ and $\|\mathbf{x}\|$, so that you can make determinations about the size of $f$ based on the size of  $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

For (c),
use
$e^x \ge 1+x$,
so
$e^{x^2} \ge 1+x^2$.